# How to access browser console in AIDE for error checking

Tags: aide-ide

Is there an equivalent of the browser console in AIDE? It took me trial and error to find out that it doesn't seem to support local storage (or at least the library that I'm usings implementation of it)

Should I wrap everything in one big try Catch block? I've googled and searched, I suspect I should be doing better error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. You can share the published web app from aide when you're running it. Open it in Firefox for Android after downloading the console add-on. It's not as fully featured as a desktop version but it's close

It feels like  poor form to answer ones own question, I earnt the tumbleweed badge for this so perhaps I can be forgiven!